# How to Resolve ClassNotFoundException with BSON in Tomcat?

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, tomcat

I'm writing a Tomcat 8 application that works fine unless I attempt to instantiate any MongoDB class in my servlet's POST handler.

According to the [Java driver documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/driver-compatibility-reference/#reference-compatibility-language-java), Mongo 3.0.x is compatible with Java 7. As the [Installation Guide](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.2/driver/getting-started/installation-guide/) describes, the normal driver with bson and mongodb-driver-core as dependencies is recommended. So I included mongodb-driver in my pom.xml and downloaded and included the dependencies as external JARs (all version 3.0.4), but received the exception and stack trace when running the servlet. I then attempted the Uber jar (mongo-java-driver), but that made no impact. Just to be able to instantiate a Document, I included just the BSON as an external JAR and then in my pom.xml, still no change.

I've also tried cleaning the Eclipse/Maven project and different versions of the dependencies.

MongoDB version: 3.2.11

Java compiler version: 1.7

Driver version: 3.0.4

Tomcat version: 8

Stack trace:

```
25-Dec-2016 14:17:41.196 SEVERE [http-nio-5000-exec-15] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [Login] in context with path [/genebase] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.bson.Document
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1295)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1147)
at seismic.servlet.Login.post(Login.java:17)
...
```

The servlet:

```
import org.bson.Document;

import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public abstract class Servlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {
        try {
            new Document();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

What could be causing this exception?

Comment: Make sure you verify the jars are available in the classpath. Basically thats all that error is saying. Go where you war is deployed and expand the war and go to WEB-INF/lib and check if the bson jar is available.

Comment: Perfect, thanks, this resolved my issue. I was able to manually create this directory and place the JARs inside. In the future I'll avoid Eclipse's Add External JARs and place any JARs directly into WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: You can do all these operations through maven. From building, packaging to deploying to tomcat.

Comment: @Veeram - and if it _is_ available there, as it is in my case..what then?